# CANVAS CON JAVASCRIP Y PDFJS

Tags: php, javascript, fpdf

Tengo el siguiente escenario:

1. tengo un formulario donde subo un PDF por inputfile, al momento de validar que es un archivo PDF lo que hago es separarlo por hoja utilizando la libreria PDFJS recorriendo todo el archivo y separarlo en tantas hojas tenga como pagina y lo coloca en un canvas.
2. aquí mi problema cuando el archivo tiene mas de 300 hojas demora mas de lo debido y lo que necesito es ejecutar otra función una vez que acabe de recorrer todo los canvas
3. como podría saber cuanto tiempo se demora en recorrer todo esos canvas y recién ejecutar mi otra función ya que llamando mi otra funcion abajo del "for" captura pero los canvas vacio ya que el for aun no acaba de recorrer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes que promisificar tus llamadas y crear un for asincrono, (esto es nuevo y hace parte de ES9 creo). De esta manera el for siempre esperara a que se resuelva o rechace la promesa que le pongas, que en tu caso deberia ser el resultado de la llamada a `vistacanvas2`.

Comment: tendras un ejemplo